# Can I use the Z-Test with estimators for mean and standard deviation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, sampling, z-test

I'm trying to select feature columns in a binary classification model.

I'd like to remove near-constant columns that don't predict the target column values very well. One way of defining this is the number of times a constant values occurs in parallel with a positive classification.

I can create dummy columns with the minimum level of match that I'm happy with and calculate their correlation. Doing this 2,000 plus times gives me a sample with a well defined mean and standard deviation for the expected correlation at that level of "matching".

My plan is then to calculate the correlation between feature column and the target column and use a z-test the left-tailed probability that the real correlation is below my minimum match value.

Can I use my calculated mean and standard deviation to perform this z-test?

Comment: For many good reasons this is unlikely to work well for variable selection.  For methods that have been found to be effective, search here for "model identification", "variable selection", and related terms.  You should find a few thousand good posts about all aspects of this problem.

Comment: What about for discarding nearly-constant columns? I don't mean variable selection in general. My plan is to use mRMR for that.

Comment: Sometimes discarding near-constant columns works, but I always worry that could throw out some of the most valuable information, so I think it's worth some study to check on that possibility. For instance, you could attempt classification without them and later see whether your classes are associated with any combination of the columns you initially threw away.  Regardless, using bivariate correlations among columns to weed them out generally *shouldn't* work unless you are lucky.

Comment: Okay, thank you again. I think I'm actually hitting on the problem now. I believe what I'm suggesting is slightly more complex than discarding on bivariate correlations. My point is, if there are near-constant columns, i.e. columns with 95% the same value and very few unique values, these columns are unlikely to contain useful data. However, they *might* contain useful data. I'd like to test if they do contain useful data by using correlation as a proxy for the number of times they feature in a "predictive group". (predictive group = some group of variables that are predictive for the target)

Comment: Right -- but correlation is a crude tool.  Maybe you should be formulating questions that focus on this particular aspect of (what is evidently) a complex problem and ask *how* to proceed rather than asking whether a particular procedure might work.

Comment: To do that I want to calculate the probability distribution of a constant value that occurs in a "predictive group" X times. Because the constant value in the near-constant column *must* feature in the predictive group (or groups) when the target is 0 or 1, I can create a dummy pairs of columns that simulate this and get their correlations. I can get the mean and standard deviation of these correlations and then use that to predict how likely it is a bivariate correlation has the underlying level of predictive groups.

Comment: Okay. I don't have it in me to ask again today! Is there terminology/ a methodology that describes what I'm talking about already? I'd rather ask a question tomorrow armed with the correct lexicon.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't follow any of that ;-).  The abstractness of the descriptions just makes them too vague.

Comment: Well, at least now we understand the issue! We can truly say it's unanswerable via abstractness and obscurity. I will update all the questions I've asked once I have an answer!

Comment: As a general question though, without background. Can I use estimators for z-test if I think they're good enough? Also, is a question like this too simple for cross validated? Should I be asking simple statistics questions on the math stack exchange?

Comment: It's not too simple: it's just hard to understand. When you have a clear, definite, mathematical question then by all means ask it on [math.se]. But currently your question wouldn't fly there, either, because you haven't said anything other than that you're contemplating conducting thousands of tests (a red flag) on correlations (another red flag) with a "z test."  Frankly, I don't think you have a Z test in mind, but perhaps are planning to exclude some extreme quantiles of an empirical correlation distribution--but I'm just guessing.

Comment: Not quite! I think it is a z-test I have in mind. But the proof is in the pudding. I'll try it with and without my method and report back. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: One of the reasons I think you might be going astray is that in a previous related question you ask for the "probability an observation is drawn from a random variable." Making such a statement would be a serious misinterpretation of a z-test.  It points in the direction of a Bayesian analysis or a prediction interval, but neither seem to be in the spirit with which you are asking your questions.